# For microphone devices NAudio is not providing "Device Number"

Tags: c#, naudio, naudio-framework

I'm using NAudio to record audio from **multiple** microphone devices, but the problem is, to assign the device I have to provide device number (in WaveIn object), which is unknown.

```
WaveIn _waveInMicrophone = new WaveIn
                {
                    DeviceNumber = ???,
                    WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1)
                };
```

How to get the **Device Number** so that i can uniquely assign device to my WaveIn object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just start from 0. Use `WaveIn.DeviceCount` to find out how many devices there are. Use `WaveIn.GetCapabilities` to find out a bit more about each one (including device name)